# Change to three way calling after monitoring two way conversation using ChanSpy ---Asterisk---

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk, telephony, freeswitch

I have a scenario that i'd like to implement using Asterisk. ↓↓

---

I'd like to have 3 participants on a phone call: A, B and C.

A and B should be able to talk to and hear each other.

C should be able to hear conversation between A and B, and also able to talk to A but not to B.

---

### I think scenario above could be done by Asterisk cmd "ChanSpy", but I also want to make monitor C to join into conversation between A, B and make it as three way calling.

I'm not thinking about using "conference room" idea for this implementation.

Is it able to accomplish scenarios above without using "conference room" ?

Please help...
Your comments, suggestions are always appriciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A and B talking to eachother means audio from A goes to B, and audio from B goes to A. ChanSpy to C means audio from A and B are mixed together and sent to C. (So you involve a mixer hera already, but a lightweight one.)

C talking to A would mean audio from C and audio from B will have to get mixed and sent to A. At this stage, you are theoretically throwing a second mixer in the game, and i say "theoretically" because i dont even know how you can practically do that. By now, i think you will be better off using a real conference, with C muted most of the time.

I understand your concern about not having everything in your system as a 3-way conference. If C talking is an occasional event, then you can start with an A-B bridge and ChanSpy C in, then when C wants to jump in the conversation you break the bridge and create a conference. This does require a little work, but it's resource-respectful :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment 8-) After several sleepless night, I have found the way to satisfy my need. I found it could be done by using "-b" command & DTMF. Could switch Monitor/Whisper/Barge mode seemlessly with out using conference function. FYI>>> http://www.voip-

Comment: You're probably talking about the `w` and `W` options. Those would connect C to either A or B, but not to both A and B at the same time. Kinda depends on how i interpreted what you wrote with the big letters and what your definition of "three way calling" is, but if it serves your purposes, fine with me :)